# Can't use Get-ADGroup in foreach loop

Tags: arrays, powershell, loops, foreach, active-directory

I want to use a `Get-ADGroup` command in nested `foreach` loops. But somehow the command results nothing back. The command and filters are corect, as you can see it at the very bottom after the loops, the same instruction works there perfectly, for whatever reason.

```cs
$file = "\\path"
$data = Import-Csv $file -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF7 |
        select -First 5

Measure-Command {
    foreach ($item in $data ) {
        $tiefe = $($item.'Tiefe')
        $pfad = $($item.'Pfad')
        $recht = $($item.'Recht')
        $trustee = $($item.'trustee')

        $LDAPDirectoryService = 'IP-Adresss'
        $DomainDN = 'o=enterprise'

        $LDAPFilter = "cn=$trustee"

        $null = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.DirectoryServices.Protocols')
        $null = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Net')

        $LDAPServer = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection $LDAPDirectoryService
        $LDAPServer.AuthType = [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.AuthType]::Anonymous
        $LDAPServer.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3
        $LDAPServer.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = $false

        $Scope = [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope]::Subtree
        $AttributeList = @('*')

        $SearchRequest = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchRequest -ArgumentList $DomainDN,$LDAPFilter,$Scope,$AttributeList

        $groups = $LDAPServer.SendRequest($SearchRequest)
        $groups

        #Prüft ob Gruppe existiert
        if ($groups.Entries.Count -eq 0) {
            Write-Host " Group not found!" `n -Foregroundcolor Red $LDAPFilter
            #Speichert alle nicht gefundenen Gruppen zur manuellen Nachbearbeitung
            Add-Content -Path \\Path -Value "$LDAPFilter"
        }

        foreach ($group in $groups.Entries) {
            #Listet alle Member der oben übergebenen Gruppe auf
            $users = $group.Attributes['member'].GetValues('string')

            foreach ($user in $users) {
                Write-Host $user
                #Hier den User zur AD Gruppe hinzufügen
                Write-Host "user zur Gruppe hinzufügen $pfad-$recht" -ForegroundColor Red

                # This little Boy doesnt work
                Get-ADGroup -Properties Name, Description -Filter 'Name -like "F-KT-*"' |
                    where {$_.Description -like "*$pfad" -and $_.Name.EndsWith($recht)}

                #Add-ADGroupMember -Identity S-1-5-21-219376080-2991882224-574971396-34759 -Members $user -Whatif
            }
        }
    }
}

# Here the command works without a fault
Get-ADGroup -Properties Name, Description -Filter 'Name -like "F-KT-*"' |
    where {$_.Description -like "*$pfad" -and $_.Name.EndsWith($recht)}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why the one is working rather than the other, but my question to you is, why do you need it there? You already have access to a group because you are inside the foreach loop. You should be able to run `Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $user`. Also, are you doing this with a full Active Directory domain, or an LDS? I might be missing a thing or two from your post though.

Comment: Its a bit tricky, I try to migrate Secrurity Groups from an LDS to AD.

Comment: So the $group value is the LDS Group Name, but now I need the AD Name to add these Users.

Answer (score 0):

I still dont know why but I found a solution working for me.

```
$AD = Get-ADGroup -Properties Name, Description -Filter 'Name -like "F-KT-*"' | where {$_.Description -like "*$pfad" -and $_.Name.endswith($recht) }
write-Host $AD.Name -ForegroundColor Yellow
```

Maybe someone can tell me why I have to declare get-ADGroup as a variable in the Loop, but outside its working without it.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a similar issue, I dont know what was happening to the data but its like it just chose a pipeline and it was none of them that I could see. Null maybe?

Anyway after my command I got it to work as intended by using | out-host

`Get-ADGroupMember $_ | select name | Out-Host`

My best guess is this forces which output to use, and prints it as expected.